# Powerpivot sum from dimension table

Tags: powerpivot, dax

I am a graduate intern at a big company and I'm having some trouble with creating a measure in PowerPivot.
I'm quite new with PowerPivot and I need some help. I am the first person to use PowerPivot in this office so I can't ask for help here.

I have a fact table that has basically all journal entries. See next table. All entries are done with a unique ID (serialnumber) for every product

```
ID  DATE     ACCOUNT#   AMOUNT
110 2010-1-1 900        $1000
```

There is a dimension table with has all accounts allocated to a specific country and expense or revenue.

```
ACCOUNT#    Expense Country
900         Revenue Germany
```

And another dimension table to split the dates.
The third dimension table contains product information, but also contains a column with a certain expense (Expense X).

```
ID  Expense X   ProductName Productcolour
110 $50          Flower      Green
```

I made sure I made the correct relations between the tables of course. And slicing works in general.

To calculate the margin I need to deduct this expense x from the revenue. I already made a measure that shows total Revenue, that one was easy.

Now I need a measure to show the total for Expense X, related to productID. So I can slice in a pivot table on date and product name etc.

The problem is that I can't use RELATED function because the serial number is used multiple times in the fact table (journal entries can have the same serial number)
And if I use the SUM or CALCULATE function it won't slice properly.

So how can I calculate the total for expense X so it will slice properly?

Comment: Based on the dummy dataset you exposed, what is the expected output?

Comment: To have the total of expense x in the product table, related to the serialnumbers. So I can make a pivot table and slice on date and serialnumber to show the margin of the products.

Answer (score 0):

Check the function `RELATEDTABLE`.

If you create a dummy dataset I can play around and send you a solution.

Comment: I made a dummy table: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7lnklrbdfm2jdr8/dummy%20table.xlsx?dl=0